# How I get the images to fade in and out individually and not altogether?

Tags: html, css, frontend, background

**I want to have a slideshow where the images fade in and out in order, however the images appear altogether and fade altogether.**

## (HTML code)

Below is the HTML code for the website, that is connected to the CSS and JS file.

```
<section class="slideshow-section">
                <!--Slideshow content -->
                <div class="slideshow-container">
                    <div class="zelda fade">
                        <img src="LegendOfZelda.png" width="240" alt = "Game 1">
                        <div class="zeldatext">
                            <p><strong>The Legend of Zelda</strong></p>
                            <p>£45.99</p>
                            <p><i>Nintendo Switch</i></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="sims fade">
                        <img src="Sims4.png" width="240" alt = "Game 2">
                        <div class="simstext">
                            <p><strong>The Sims 4</strong></p>
                            <p>Free</p>
                            <p><i>Multiple Platforms</i></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="fifa fade">
                        <img src="FC24.png" width="240" alt = "Game 3">
                        <div class="fifatext">
                            <p><strong>EA FC 24</strong></p>
                            <p>£41.99</p>
                            <p><i>Multiple Platforms</i></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <!-- Navigation dots -->
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        <span class="dot"></span>
                        <span class="dot"></span>
                        <span class="dot"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

## (CSS code)

Here is the CSS code; I feel like my problem has something to do with this code but I can't figure out where.

```
.slideshow-section {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00090a00;
    height: 0%;
  
}
  
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.zelda, .sims, .fifa {
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 70%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}



.zeldatext, .simstext, .fifatext{
    color:rgb(185, 110, 250);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -70%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.fade{
    animation:  fade 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0%, 100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    25%, 75% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

## JavaScript code

I don't think my javascript code is working either because this should be what's making them change by slideshow.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    let slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();
  
    function showSlides() {
      let i;
      const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('fifa','sims','zelda');
      const dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
      
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      
      slideIndex++;
      
      if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
      }
      
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
      
      setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change slide every 5 seconds
    }
  });
```

[Screenshot of the slideshow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55zlh.jpg)